# Triggering a Jenkins backup from the command line with the Backup plugin

Tags: curl, jenkins, backup, command-line-interface

#### The problem

backup policies on my network imply giving a path to backup and an optional command to run just before, so that I can prepare the backup

I need to backup my Jenkins configuration. Simply giving a path to the Jenkins data directory is not an option as:

1. I just need to backup the configuration
2. the total disk usage for that directory, ~ 80GB, is far beyond reasonable backup size (99% consist of non-critical workspace data)

#### So far

I installed the [Backup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Backup+Plugin) and found reasonably good settings for it. Now I wonder if I can trigger it remotely using a bash script. I understand that using `curl` on the /jenkins/backup/launchBackup url should do the trick, but I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error as I'm hitting the URI as an anonymous user, and couldn't find a solution to login or get around this.

So does anyone knows of a simple way to trigger a *configuration only* backup from the command line ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Jenkins wiki describes how to [perform an authenticated login in scripts](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients). Short answer: Go to the Configure screen from your user page and get the API token, then use it as your password when running your script.

I haven't tried it with the Backup plugin, but it works for running regular builds so it should work for any scriptable invocation.

Without authentication:

```
$ curl http://jenkins:8080/job/my%20job/build
[ HTML page saying "Authentication required" ]
```

With authentication:

```
$ curl --user dbacher:$MY_API_TOKEN http://jenkins:8080/job/my%20job/build
[ returns nothing and the build starts ]
```

---

**Update**: fixed the *jobs* typo, thanks for the comments.

Comment: I'm using Jenkins ver. 1.517 and it's `/job/`, not `/jobs/`. Other than that, worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Bacher's answer didn't work for me. I needed to do:

```
$ curl http://jenkins:8080/job/MY_JOB_NAME/build?build
```

It's job, not jobs, and I needed the ?build on the end.

Comment: The question was primarily focused on authentication. Useful correction anyway.